# Static module declaration using Durandal and Require

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

I'm using Durandal and Require for my SPA application. Also I'm using HotTowel template from John Papa.

For my modules, I need some of them to be created per request and some of them to be singleton.

```
define([], function(){
    var bookId = ko.observable();
    var bookName = ko.observable();

    return {
        bookId: bookId,
        bookName: bookName
    };
}
```

The above module seems to return a new instance for each composition use like:

```
compose: {model: 'viewmodels/book'}
```

But what if I want the view model to be same in all compositions. For example I want a viewmodel for my login named `loginInfo` which will be used in lots of places, so it shouldn't initialize on each composition as it was initiated somewhere at first login.

```
compose: {model: 'viewmodels/loginInfo'}
```

Comment: The above module indeed returns a singleton see http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module/. What make you believe it doesn't?

Comment: indeed, the only time it will return something new is when you return a constructor function.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit, seems you're right. It's my fault.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis as I'm new to javascript world, I mixed up these concepts. The problem is that I thought in RequireJs, if we return function it means it is a constructor function, and if we return an object, it's a singleton object!

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis don't you want to post the answer!? so I could close this question as it resolved!?

Comment: @mehrandvd feel free to mark the answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Durandal, if a viewmodel returns an object

```
define(function(require) {
    return { a: 1, b: 2 }
});
```

Durandal will persist the same object. If a viewmodel returns a constructor

```
define(function(require) {
    return Function() {
        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
    }
});
```

Durandal will create a new object by invoking the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your brief and complete answer.

Comment: And exactly THAT is the big problem if TypeScript is used. What is "export"-ed is a constructor - thus the viewmodel is always initialized when a view is activated.
Of course I could use exports directly on the module level, but in my opinion that would be no improvement over the "old" js object notation. Is there a way to tell Durandal to use one and only one instance of a viewmodel?

Comment: @okieh You have to export an object rather than a function (as specified in the answer above). Can't you do something like `export new ClassName();` in TypeScript?